# How can I use react-loadable with react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-loadable

I am trying to implement an application that has 10-15 pages. That works with react-router well but I should use react-loadable to have a Spinner and loading effect ...

But how can I import router components inside the loadable ?

I should create one const variable for each component ?

Like this :

```js
const Home = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./Home'),
    loading: Loading,
});

const News = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./News'),
    loading: Loading,
});

const Gallery = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./Gallery'),
    loading: Loading,
});

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <Router>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/news" component={News} />
              <Route path="/gallery" component={Gallery} />
          </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Or it's possible with other tricks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. You don't need to use react-loadable.

Demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2opxlwm85).

If you want to make loader for images and other components until they are `onLoad`, you can use [react-content-loader](https://github.com/danilowoz/react-content-loader) instead to create skeleton screens (See `components/Image.js` in demo). It could make "almost" perfect loader. So far, this is what I can do. I have no idea to detect `onLoad` for css :(

You can create a new file named `routes.js` which includes all pages.

```
- /src
-- /pages
--- Gallery.js
--- Home.js
--- News.js
--- withBase.js
-- App.js
-- routes.js
```

**routes.js**

```
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Gallery from './pages/Gallery';
import News from './pages/News';
// Add as much as you want...

export default [
   {
       path: '/',
       component: Home,
   },
   {
       path: '/gallery',
       component: Gallery,
   },
   {
       path: '/news',
       component: News,
   },
];
```

You need to create a high order component that will wrap each page.

**withBase.js (HOC)**

```
import React from "react";

export default WrappedComponent =>
  class extends React.Component {
    state = {
      isLoading: true
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.hideLoader();
    }

    hideLoader = () => {
      // This is for demo purpose
      const proc = new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), 3000);
      });
      proc.then(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false }));
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.isLoading ? <p>Loading...</p> : <WrappedComponent />}
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
```

Usage: e.g. `export default withBase(Home)`.

Then, in `App.js` just loop the routes.

```
    <Switch>
      {routes.map(route => (
        <Route
          exact
          key={route.path}
          path={route.path}
          component={route.component}
        />
      ))}
    </Switch>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a cute trick ! but this check only componentDidMount() and the loading not be real (for all images, css, js etc. ) ... can I use something like window.onload() to check even images or other assets and implement a perfect loading ?!

Comment: You might be interested with [skeleton screens](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-speed-up-your-ux-with-skeleton-screens). I can make a simple demo later, if you are pleased to wait.